# Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin - Device is not shown on VS

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2015

I have **Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with Xamarin** inside **Windows 7 Virtual Machine**.  I have my android device connected to the physical machine and Yes the android phone is recognized in the Virtual Machine, since it's shown in the **My Computer** of Virtual Machine, and also displayed in Other devices under **Device Manager**.

When I created **Cross-Platform Blank App (Native Portable)** project in VS2015 and Set **App.Droid** as startup Project, I can't see my phone. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check unsupported devices under list of devices to run (or it is just Start button if you don't have any devices). If your phone is there that means your project has higher API level as Minimum target than the phone's API. 
   If phone is not even in that list then
2. Check on the phone if Developer mode is enabled and inside you have

   - USB debugging enabled
   - Stay awake
   - (Optionally) Allow mock locations

Comment: how do I check the api leve lof my project, and the api of my phone?

Comment: okay I get it now, API of phone depends on the version. i'll check it out for a while

Comment: how do I check api level of project in visual studio?

Comment: go to project Properties. You will find it there. Do you see your device as Unsupported?

Comment: in Devices under control panel, I can see my device, in visual studio, I can't see the device

Comment: Minimum on vs project is API Level 15, my Phone is API 20  but still can't see my deice, (Debug) (Any CPU) (App3.Android)

Comment: did you enable Developer mode?

Comment: yeah developer mode is enabled, usb debugging is checked, I already tried revoking usb debug authorization and restarting the device and virtual machine

Comment: sometimes VS doesn't show device if it is connected before VS starts. Try to close and start VS while device is connected. I have never tried to run from VM, may be that is the problem.